# Trying to evaluate Riemann's ζ(4) using infinite product representation of sin(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

It is known that the sine function can be written as an infinite product:
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2 \pi^2})
$$
For $x$ sufficiently small I collect equal powers of $x$:
$$
\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+O(x^7)}{x}=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(k \pi)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(k \pi)^2}\sum_{l=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(l \pi)^2}+O(x^6)
$$
or

$$
{1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}+O(x^6)}=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(k \pi)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(k \pi)^2}\sum_{l=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(l \pi)^2}+O(x^6)
$$

The constant term cancels out. The $x^2$ term drops out if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2)
$$
which is a known value of the zeta function. Now we have to balance the $x^4$ terms. We get

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{l=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{l^2}=\frac{\pi^4}{120}
$$

Just what is this monstrocity? Is it in any way related to $\zeta(4)$ which is $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ ?
So close and yet so far away... How to continue?
Please help!

Comment: After showing $$\zeta(2)^2 = \zeta(4) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \sum_{l=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{l^2}, $$ just replace for the double sum and $\zeta(2)$.

Comment: **Hint :** $a^2+b^2=a^2-(ib)^2.$

Comment: Thank you Sir !